# React grid layout custom resize handle is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-grid-layout

According to [React-Grid-Layout doc](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout#grid-layout-props)

`resizeHandle?: ReactElement<any> | ((resizeHandleAxis: ResizeHandleAxis, ref: ReactRef<HTMLElement>) => ReactElement<any>)`

can be used to implement custom resize handle for the grid items.

In my case this is not working. It's not even throwing any errors.

Code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-jwfn3?file=/index.js

**Note:** If I remove `resizeHandle={<BottomRightHandle />}` grid items will get default resize handler, Which is working fine.

CustomResizeHandle.js

```
import React from "react";

const SouthEastArrow = () => (
  <svg
    width="20px"
    height="20px"
    version="1.1"
    viewBox="0 0 100 100"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <path d="m70.129 67.086l1.75-36.367c-0.035156-2.6523-2.9414-3.6523-4.8164-1.7773l-8.4531 8.4531-17.578-17.574c-2.3438-2.3438-5.7188-1.5625-8.0586 0.78125l-13.078 13.078c-2.3438 2.3438-2.4141 5.0117-0.074219 7.3516l17.574 17.574-8.4531 8.4531c-1.875 1.875-0.83594 4.8203 1.8164 4.8555l36.258-1.8594c1.6836 0.019531 3.1328-1.2812 3.1133-2.9688z" />
  </svg>
);

const CustomHandle = (props) => (
  <div
    style={{
      background: "#fff",
      borderRadius: "2px",
      border: "1px solid #ddd",
      position: "absolute",
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
      padding: 0,
      cursor: "se-resize"
    }}
    {...props}
  />
);

const BottomRightHandle = () => (
  <CustomHandle>
    <SouthEastArrow />
  </CustomHandle>
);

export default BottomRightHandle;
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Grid, Row, Col } from "react-flexbox-grid";

import { Responsive, WidthProvider } from "react-grid-layout";

import "../../node_modules/react-grid-layout/css/styles.css";
import "../../node_modules/react-resizable/css/styles.css";

import BottomRightHandle from "./CustomResizeHandle";

const ResponsiveGridLayout = WidthProvider(Responsive);

const Layout = (props) => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
    { i: "a", x: 0, y: 0, w: 2, h: 1 },
    { i: "b", x: 2, y: 0, w: 2, h: 1 }
  ]);

  return (
    <ResponsiveGridLayout
      className="layout"
      layouts={{ lg: items }}
      breakpoints={{ lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768 }}
      cols={{ lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6 }}
      resizeHandles={["se"]}
      resizeHandle={<BottomRightHandle />}
    >
      {items.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={item.i}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#ccc" }}
            data-grid={{ x: item.x, y: item.y }}
          >
            {item.i}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </ResponsiveGridLayout>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Layout />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 7):

Please try to import the below react-grid-layout css files. Then you will see the handles.

```
import "react-grid-layout/css/styles.css";
import "react-resizable/css/styles.css";
```

Comment: you are God man! saved many hours of work with these two imports.

Answer (score 3):

According to the doc, you have to have the `react-resizable-handle` and `react-resizable-handle-${handleAxis}` in your custom handle component, and pass the `handleAxis` and `ref` in from the `ReactGridLayout`'s `resizeHandle` prop.

What worked for me was:

```js
type ResizeHandleAxis = 's' | 'w' | 'e' | 'n' | 'sw' | 'nw' | 'se' | 'ne';

type ResizeHandleProps = {
  handleAxis: ResizeHandleAxis;
}
const MyHandle = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, ResizeHandleProps>(({ handleAxis }, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref}
      className={`react-resizable-handle react-resizable-handle-${handleAxis}`}
    >
    </div>
  );
});
```

```js
    <ReactGridLayout {...}
      resizeHandles={[ "n", "e", "s", "w", "ne", "se", "nw", "sw" ]}
      resizeHandle={(handleAxis: ResizeHandleAxis, ref: React.Ref<HTMLDivElement>) =>
        <MyHandle ref={ref} handleAxis={handleAxis} />
      }
    >
      { children }
    </ReactGridLayout>
```

Then you can do extra stuff in this new component. But you'll have to use css classes to erase the default styling and customizing the new styles

Erasing default CSS

```css
.react-resizable-handle {
  background-image: none;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.react-grid-item > .react-resizable-handle.react-resizable-handle-n,
.react-grid-item > .react-resizable-handle.react-resizable-handle-e,
.react-grid-item > .react-resizable-handle.react-resizable-handle-s,
.react-grid-item > .react-resizable-handle.react-resizable-handle-w,
.react-grid-item > .react-resizable-handle.react-resizable-handle-ne,
.react-grid-item > .react-resizable-handle.react-resizable-handle-nw,
.react-grid-item > .react-resizable-handle.react-resizable-handle-se,
.react-grid-item > .react-resizable-handle.react-resizable-handle-sw
{
  transform: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.react-grid-item > .react-resizable-handle::after {
  border: none;
  content: none;
}
```

You can also use other classes instead of having to clear the default styling as per the doc, but then it's not super clear and I didn't get to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that this feature is not yet implemented in `react-grid-layout` although it's been described in the documentation!! And it causes lots of confusion. Any way, I found a workaround to apply customized icon for resizing. First, we need to create our customized component with an absolute position in our desired place (as you have done it by creating `BottomRightHandle` component). Then, pass your `BottomRightHandle` inside `ResponsiveGridLayout` component as below:

```
 <ResponsiveGridLayout
      className="layout"
      layouts={{ lg: items }}
      breakpoints={{ lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768 }}
      cols={{ lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6 }}
      resizeHandles={["se"]}
      // resizeHandle={<BottomRightHandle />}
    >
      {items.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={item.i}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#ccc" }}
            data-grid={{ x: item.x, y: item.y }}
          >
            {item.i}
            <BottomRightHandle />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </ResponsiveGridLayout>
```

and then, create a css file in order to remove and disappear the default resize arrow by these styles:

```
.react-grid-item > .react-resizable-handle::after {
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.react-resizable-handle {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Please check the [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-cois1?file=/index.js:608-1172)

Please keep in mind that the `resizeHandles` position (in this case `se`) should be the same as the `BottomRightHandle` component's absolute position.